# How can I schedule the execution of a PHP script on Windows

Tags: php, windows, email, scheduled-tasks

For my reminder system app I need to send emails, one day before the *event* . The database stores the reminders with `date`,`time`,`user_id`. Is there any way I can schedule an email that automatically gets sent a day before the event occurs ?

Comment: Windows: [Schedule tasks](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/schedule-a-task). Unix: [Cronjob](http://superuser.com/questions/67352/run-a-command-every-week-with-cron).

Comment: This isn't really a very constructive question. Never-the-less, do you have an email script already made?

Comment: @F4r-20 Yeah. It is a simple script that uses the mail function to send the email

Comment: Are you on a Windows machine?

Comment: @SuhailGupta Please see my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Create a batch file that will run the script**

Open up notepad, add this command, with your own attributes:

```
"PATH_TO_PHP.EXE" -f "SCRIPT_TO_RUN.PHP"
```

So it may look like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe" -f "C:\tasks\task.php")
```

Save this file as a `.bat` file (Batch file).

(OK so creating a batch file isn't completely necessary but what if you wanted to expand on this task? Right?)

**2) Have task scheduler run the task**

Open up *Task Scheduler* (You'll find it in *Accessories > System Tools*, or just search for 'taskschd.msc')

Create a task.

Give it a name, Create a [**trigger**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the specified day.

Now go to the Actions tab, hit New and it should say 'Start a program' by default.

Browse to the batch file that you just made, click OK and you're done.

Comment: Is there a concept of `multiple threads` in php ? Like there is in java.Let alone script schedule an email..It should be like query the database at regular intervals and if there is an event that should be reported back to the user..an email be sent to him

Comment: You can make task scheduler run at any interval you'd like